# Getting a Package Validation Error for Row Count SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

New to SSIS. I'm trying to connect OData Source [SharePoint] and just want to view it in the SSIS Package. When I run my solution, it comes up with the following error message:

```
> TITLE: Package Validation Error
> ------------------------------
> 
> Package Validation Error
> 
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> 
> Error at Data Flow Task [Row Count [50]]: The variable "(null)"
> specified by VariableName property is not a valid variable. Need a
> valid variable name to write to.
> 
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Row Count" failed validation
> and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
> 
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed
> validation.
> 
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
> 
>  (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)
> 
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
> 
> OK
> ------------------------------
```

I have tried following this suggested solution but with the same results:

[SSIS Row Count: Getting a null variable error where there is clearly a selected variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24974/ssis-row-count-getting-a-null-variable-error-where-there-is-clearly-a-selected)

Can someone please tell me what this error message means and what I can do to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to indicate that the Rowcount component doesn't have a package variable set, to which to write the result of its Count.  Double-click on this component and set the variable.  Watch out that SSIS variable names are case-sensitive.

You can have a valid-looking variable name in the Rowcount box, which in fact no longer exists in the package.  So click on the drop-down, even if a variable name is there, to check that it's actually an existing package variable.